# Weird code making Bootstrap scrollspy work, how do I track the bug?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, scrollspy

So the following selector and definition is somehow allowing my scrollspy to mostly behave the way it is supposed to in Chrome. Without it, the scrollspy jumps to halfway down the screen. The CSS looks like this.

```
ul.scrspy.affix {
  top: 1.85rem;
}
```

This chaining of classes is very odd and I want to udnerstand what is going on and find a better way to accomplish what it is doing. Additionally, when I go into the element inspector in my rendered page, the browser is changing my "affix" class to "affix-top" which also very odd.

I welcome any recommendations on how to track down the issues, and am open to suggestions on how to fix the problem.

FYI, my scrollspy has two levels of children, so it is a more complex list than the one found on getboostrap.com. There are examples of this on the lesscss.com site.

Comment: For us to be able to see what is going on we need the code that you are using. Also a isolated example of the issue would be very helpful but it's not compulsory.

Answer (score 0):

After quite a bit of investigation, I resolved several problems with the above.

First the affix and affix-top class change is necessary to allow the side-nav to be positioned int eh correct spot for when the page loads versus when the user is scrolling.

- affix-top on page load: removes the postion: fixed; property from your element so that it start in normal document flow and doesn't cover up your header content
- affix on scroll: add the position: fixed; property to your element when scrolling

In order for this to work properly you have to use something similar to the above selector. A technique called 'chaining' which allows you to target multiple elements, id's, and classes to find a unique element. In this case, it says that i'm looking for a ul that has the classes scrspy and affix. The target must have all three attributes for it to be selected.

Taking all of this together, the above selector is telling my scrollspy element that when the user is scrolling, it's top position should be 1.85 rem. This is to create a bit of space between the first list item in the menu and the top of the screen. Since the affix class isn't applied when the user it either 1) at the top of the page or 2) when the page first loads, this style won't apply and the object will return to normal document flow.